# href in DataTables

Tags: javascript, datatable

I am trying to insert a href into one of my columns in DataTables but Im having some issues since I need the actual href to show my slug and then the full company name.

**Example how it should be formatted:** `<a href="slug">"company"</a>` 

**Real data:** `<a href="toyota-cars">Toyota Cars</a>`.

I am using columns.render which seems to be the correct function but I can't wrap my head around how I can get 'company' between the a tags. The function does not even make use of the "data" specifier, instead it takes the data first in my ajax file which in this case is slug.

**My DataTable.js file**

```
ajax: '/api/datatable', 

columns: [
  { data: 'slug' },
  { data: 'company' },
],

"columnDefs": [ 
  { targets: [0, 1], visible: true},

 { "targets": 0,
     "data": "This doesnt even seem needed?",
     "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
     return '<a href="/company/'+data+'">full company name</a>';
     } 
   }

],
```

Comment: I am a little bit confused about what you are trying to get. Perhaps it would be clearer, if you would specify "expected vs actual" results, rather than "should be vs real data". Is "real data" something you are trying to achieve or something you are getting? On the side note, `data` param in `render` function is based on `columns.data` you specified earlier. Since `target === 0`, means you are taking the data from the first column. All together, means you are replacing `data` in the HTML string with whatever DataTables will find for "slug" column.

Answer (score 0):

I will go ahead and give an answer, based on the assumption that you are trying to merge values of 2 columns. If my assumption is not correct, please, update the question to clarify "expected vs actual" results.

You are using `data` parameter in `render` function. That parameter is based on the value you specified in `columns.data`. In your case (with `target === 0`), `data` will contain the value that DataTable got for `{ data: 'slug' }` column.

If you want to merge values from different columns into one, then `render` function is the correct way to do it. However, instead of `data`, you should use `row` parameter, which contains all key-value fields for a row.

For example:

```
// ...
"targets": 0,
"data": null,
"render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
    return '<a href="/company/'+row.slug+'">'+row.company+'</a>';
    // or whatever your row object key-value structure is
}
// ...
```